# sessionStorage is not replacing

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.admin_email;
$scope.admin_password;
$scope.onSelect = function(admin_email,admin_password){
    console.log( admin_email,admin_password)
  console.log("User Name: ", $scope.admin_email, 
              "Password : ", $scope.admin_password);
    var mydata = {
      admin_email : $scope.admin_email,
      admin_password : $scope.admin_password
    }
    $http({
      async: true,
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login',            
        data : mydata
    }).then(function successCallback(response){       
    if(response.status==200){
      console.log({response});
      $rootScope.isLogged=true;

      setTimeout(function(){
      window.sessionStorage.accessToken = response.data.token;
    }, 1000)

      $("#loginModal").modal("hide");
    //  console.log($("#loginModal"));
    setTimeout(function(){
      window.location='#/dashboard'
    }, 1000)


    }
    else{
      alert('login password or username incorrect')
    }
    },
    function errorCallback (response) {            
        alert("some error occurred. Check the console.");
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

This code window.sessionStorage.accessToken = response.data.token; is not working,it is a login api here window.sessionStorage.accessToken is not replacing

1. List item

---

it is showing such errors

> Object ata: null error: true message: code: "invalid_token" inner: expiredAt: "2019-03-19T09:22:27.000Z" message: "jwt expired" name: "TokenExpiredError" proto: Object message: "jwt expired" name: "UnauthorizedError" status: 401 proto: Object status: 500 proto: Object

Comment: Object
ata: null
error: true
message:
code: "invalid_token"
inner:
expiredAt: "2019-03-19T09:22:27.000Z"
message: "jwt expired"
name: "TokenExpiredError"
__proto__: Object
message: "jwt expired"
name: "UnauthorizedError"
status: 401
__proto__: Object
status: 500
__proto__: Object

Comment: it is showing such errors

Comment: Which block this error is showing? Is it in the `success` or `error`.